# Chat bubble with UI Bezier Path

Tags: swift, swiftui, uibezierpath

I want to create the chat bubble with UI Bezier Path but I am new on Bezier Path please help me in this regard. Thanks

```
private func getRightBottomBubblePath(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    let width = rect.width
    let height = rect.height
    let path = Path { p in
        p.move(to: CGPoint(x: 25, y: height))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:  20, y: height))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 20),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: 8, y: height),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: 0, y: height - 8))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 20))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 20, y: 0),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 8),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: 8, y: 0))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 21, y: 0))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 20),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: width - 12, y: 0),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: 8))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 11))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height - 1),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width + 0.05, y: height - 0.01))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 11, y: height - 4),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: width - 4, y: height + 0.5),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: width - 8, y: height - 1))
        p.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: width - 25, y: height),
                   control1: CGPoint(x: width - 16, y: height),
                   control2: CGPoint(x: width - 20, y: height))
        
    }
    return path
}
```

I got this result by using it but I need handle which came out must be in Centre Right.
[image]

[image: Added the picture I want bubble like that.]

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: I added code which I used to get handle from Bottom Right corner but I want that from Centre Right.

Comment: it's easier to do this drawing in https://www.paintcodeapp.com/ draw, get code.

Comment: FWIW there are also a few apps out there that allows you to draw a bezier on your device and then get the code, similar to paintcodeapp I think.